# ArrayList JAVA duvida

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um objeto "ItemSolicCompra" e dentro desse objeto tem outro objeto chamado "Produto" e produto tem atributos (nome, id, etc...). Tenho um List que em algumas ocasiões esses produtos se repetem (id, nome, qtde).

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu pegar  o produto "x@123" e "x@456" que tem atributos iguais, jogar em uma lista e somar suas quantidades, pois no meu for ele fica passando infinitamente pelos objetos e contabilizando. A soma deveria dar 10 mas continua a executar fazendo (...15...20...25...30...35), sendo que a soma máxima da quantidade dos objetos deveria ser 10.

```
private int calculaQtde(_Produto produto, _Compra compra) {

    int somaTotal = 0;
    for(_ItemOrcamento itemOrcamento:compra.getItens()){
        for (_SolicCompra solicCompra:itemOrcamento.getOrcamento().getCotacao().getSolicitacoes()){
           for (_ItemSolicCompra itemSolicCompra:solicCompra.getItens()){
               if (itemSolicCompra.getProduto().getId() == produto.getId()) {
                            somaTotal += itemSolicCompra.getQtde();
              }
           }

        }

    }
    return somaTotal;
}
```

Comment: Se entendi bem seu código, tanto o objeto `ItemSolicCompra` quanto o objeto `Produto` que está dentro dele têm um campo `quantidade`, correto? Se é este o caso, sua lógica falha porque você está somando a quantidade de cada `ItemSolicCompra` em vez de apenas somar a do `Produto` que tenham o mesmo `id`. Nesse caso, você teria que acessar o produto e só então pegar o atributo de quantidade. O `if` ficaria assim: `somaTotal += itemSolicCompra.getProduto().getQtde()`. Se entendi errado, me corrija.

Comment: Olá @StatelessDev,  o problema é que o produto só passa a ter quantidade em itemSolicCompra.. apenas o objeto Produto não tem  Qtde()